# Special escaping for crontab

Tags: bash, cron, rhel

I have the following user crontab entry on a RHEL 6 machine (sensitive values have been replaced):

```
MAILTO=cron-errors@organisation.com
0 5 * * * ~/bin/app_state.sh host-arg 9200 > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +%F).json
```

Which produces this entry in `/var/log/cron`:

```
Apr 23 05:00:08 host CROND[13901]: (dbjobs) CMD (~/bin/app_state.sh host-arg 9200 > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +)
```

But no file.

After changing the statement to:

```
43 5 * * * ~/bin/app_state.sh host-arg 9200 > ~/state/app-state-static.json
```

I get a better log entry and the file is created at `~/state/app-state-static.json`

I'm sure there's some issue with not escaping the `+%F` but can't for the life of me find details of how I should be escaping it. I could wrap the filename generation inside another shell script but this is more easy to read for people coming looking for the file.

Comment: Did you try to escape it like `date +\%F`

Comment: Btw, this question would be more appropriate on another site, e.g., http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ (hence the close requests).

Comment: Documented in the [crontab(5)](http://man.cx/crontab(5)) man page.

Comment: `+\%F` did the trick. I'll re ask on unix stack exchange so the answer can go on record but is there a clean way to close it out here?

Comment: Now that you have your answer it's useless to ask it on another site (especially this might be a FAQ so your question might be tagged as duplicate). Just leave everything as it is! prosperity will tell.

Comment: The [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) actually says "There are several reasons for why a cron job wouldn't run as expected: 1. Using percent signs, as in date +%F"

Answer (score 15):

As [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) says, percent characters are problematic in crontabs; % gets converted to a newline:

```
[..] > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +%F).json
```

would run command as

```
[..] > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +\nF).json
```

“Escaping” percent characters is possible, but the escape character gets executed in the command. A job like following would run the command with \ in front of percent character.

0 5 * * * ~/bin/app_state.sh host-arg 9200 > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +%F).json

One way to circumvent this problem is to have the command in a script and execute that as a cron job:

/usr/local/bin/app_state_cron.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

~/bin/app_state.sh host-arg 9200 > ~/state/app-state-$(hostname)-$(date +%F).json
```

And in crontab:

```
0 5 * * * /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/app_state_cron.sh
```